# How to prevent Blue Yeti microphone from setting default audio output

Tags: sound, usb, microphone

How do you stop a USB audio peripheral from automatically being set as the default audio output device when it's plugged in?

I have a Blue Yeti microphone connected to a USB hub that I routinely connect my laptop into. Since the Blue Yeti has a headphone jack option, it also technically registers as a USB audio speaker.

Unfortunately, what this means is whenever I plug my laptop into the USB hub, it auto switches to the Blue Yeti for both audio input *and* output, effectively disabling audio output on my laptop until I open sound settings and switch audio output back to the built-in speakers.

I like that it switches the microphone to Blue Yeti automatically, since it's a much better mic than my laptop's built-in mic, but since I don't use the headphone jack, I don't want it to switch to the audio output device. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest method is to connect your microphone, open pavucontrol (or pavucontrol-qt) tab `Configuration` and change profile of your mic to `Analog stereo input`. Logout and your setting will be saved.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.