# Blue Yeti mic stops working after suspending on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, pulseaudio, microphone

similar to [this question for Ubuntu 21.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412824/blue-yeti-microphone-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-21-10)

I have a Blue Yeti microphone plugged into my ThinkPad.

When I wake up my PC from suspension the microphone isn't working anymore, e.g. with Sound Recorder or Microsoft Teams (web app):

[image]

My workaround so far is to unplug the Blue Yeti and plug it back in.
However this also changed my sound output settings
[image: sound output settings: "Speakers - Blue Microphones" is activated]

To remedy the output change, [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1380635/1065531), I set the Blue Yeti to "input device" only on pavucontrol (although it also has output capabilities).

What remains is: How can I get rid of the need to physically reconnect the microphone at all?

Comment: I have the same issue. It happens on boot or when I suspend the PC

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you may be able to "soft" reset the usb device after a suspend. There's a tool called [usb-reset](https://github.com/ralight/usb-reset) which you can install and run when this happens to reset the device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately soft reset wasn't enough for Microsoft Teams application (still showed "microphone isn't working"). I had to physically unplug.

Comment: That's a shame. Another option is to buy a USB hub which has switched ports. That way you can leave it plugged in, and just press the "off" button on the port that the microphone is attached to. It will save wear and tear, and is pretty quick to "reboot" the port. It does the equivalent of unplugging and re-plugging. They're pretty cheap, and work fine. I have one here.